# PHP and Dialog Boxes to pass a request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have MySQL queries that generate lists that they are actually links to other PHP scripts like deleting a record etc.. and looks like this:

```
<a href="delete_record.php?id=1">Title A</a></br>
<a href="delete_record.php?id=2">Title B</a></br>
<a href="delete_record.php?id=3">Title C</a></br>
...
<a href="delete_record.php?id=xyz">Title n</a></br>
```

What I want to do is to open an "dialog box" and confirm or cancel the request when someone use the link.

I know that I can do it with jQuery by using OnClick but I have no idea how after someone clicks "Confirm" to pass the request to the delete_record.php script or to any other php script.

Comment: Make use of a modal like the bootstrap modal, this is just a div where you can place two buttons in (cancel / confirm) and place an a-tag around it.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/

Comment: You can use ajax and jQuery of plain javascript. Here a link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: you could use a simple `confirm` dialog - basic but easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript function [confirm()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) like below.

```html
<a href="delete_record.php?id=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >Title A</a></br>
<a href="delete_record.php?id=2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >Title B</a></br>
<a href="delete_record.php?id=3" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Title C</a></br>
...
<a href="delete_record.php?id=xyz" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Title n</a></br>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a library for this you can store the record id as an easily accessible attribute of the element. Your generated HTML would look something like:

```
<a data-id="1" href="delete_record.php?id=1">Title A</a></br>
<a data-id="2" href="delete_record.php?id=2">Title B</a></br>
<a data-id="3" href="delete_record.php?id=3">Title C</a></br>
...
<a data-id="xyz" href="delete_record.php?id=xyz">Title n</a></br>
```

Then bind to the click event handler of the a tag and access the ID from the elements data-id attribute and update the URL that is shown to the user via the confirm button in the modal.

Answer (score 1):

- Bind click event on anchor tag via javascript.
- In event callback function, you will get event object as an arguments.
- Call event.preventDefault() method. This will block default behaviour of anchor click.
- Get href value and store it in a variable (url) inside callback function.
- Open a popup, which will have confirm and cancel button.
- On confirm click, replace current window url. window.location.href = url.
- On cancel click, close the popup.